# chmod with wildcard inside symlink

Tags: wildcard, symlink, chmod

I'm setting up Tomcat on Centos according to https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-centos-7 , but with a twist: I put Tomcat in `/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.6` and then set up a symbolic link:

```
sudo ln -s /opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.6 /opt/tomcat
```

Now I change the group ownership of `/opt/tomcat` to `tomcat`:

```
sudo chgrp -R tomcat /opt/tomcat/conf
```

Then I give the `tomcat` group write access to the configuration directory:

```
sudo chmod g+rwx /opt/tomcat/conf
```

But here is the problem: I try to give the `tomcat` group read access to all the configuration files:

```
sudo chmod g+r /opt/tomcat/conf/*
```

That gives me an error: `chmod: cannot access ‘/opt/tomcat/conf/*’: No such file or directory`

What? Does `chmod` not accept wildcards? Or does it not look inside symbolic links? What's going on?

Note that I got around it by doing this:

```
sudo chmod g+r -R /opt/tomcat/conf
```

Does that give me effectively the same thing? (I know that it additionally makes the directory readable by the group, but that seems inconsequential --- the group could already read the directory.) Why doesn't the wildcard version work?

Comment: Do you have any files in the directory?

Comment: Yes, the standard Tomcat `conf/` files that always come with a Tomcat distribution.

Comment: Does the user you run as have +rx permissions on the directory? (Your user, not root or tomcat). This is required to expand globs.

Comment: No; doesn't `sudo` take care of this?

Comment: No. Globs are expanded by the shell before sudo and chmod runs.

Comment: Crazy!! OK, this is a "gotcha" that I didn't know about. Could you put it in an actual answer so that I can accept it here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Globs are expanded by the current shell. This happens before sudo and chown are ever invoked.

If the current shell doesn't have access to list the files, the glob will be treated as unmatched and just left alone. This makes `chmod` try to access a file literally named `*`, which fails.

```
root# echo /root/.*
/root/.bash_history /root/.bashrc ...

user$ sudo echo /root/.*
/root/.*
```

The same is true for command substitution, process substitution and other expansions, which are similarly unaffected by sudo:

```
root# echo $(whoami)
root

user$ sudo echo $(whoami)
user
```

The shell is also responsible for pipes and redirects, which are also set up before sudo ever runs:

```
root# echo 60 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
(command exits successfully)

user$ sudo echo 60 > /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
bash: /proc/sys/vm/swappiness: Permission denied
```

In Unix terms, `sudo` is wrapper for `execve(2)`, and therefore can't help with anything that you can't do through an `execve` call. If you need shell functionality from the target user, you need to manually invoke that shell:

```
user$ sudo sh -c 'chmod g+r /opt/tomcat/conf/*'
```